# Why does he keep his gun backwards?

Tags: character, ride-along-2

In Ride Along 2, Kevin Hart's character - known for being a clutz - when **in his officer uniform** appeared to have his gun backwards. I rented the movie (now returned before posting this question).

If I did see this correctly, was this an intentional wardrobe decision to add dimension to the character? Or was this a wardrobe malfunction that went overlooked?

Answer (score 2):

I doubt it was a goof that was overlooked.  It could be an intentional "gaffe" to emphasize his ineptness.

Also, there were some westerns where the gunslinger prefers reaching across his body for a less restricted "draw" and wears his guns backwards. No idea if that's a real thing, but definitely was intended for a certain amount of badass "cool," so it would also be an intentional thing where this somewhat inept officer wears his guns like that in a lame attempt to look cooler or tougher than he is.

Or, he wears it like that intentionally, for the reasons stated in the second paragraph, but because he actually prefers the draw motion across the body.  Was his holster on the opposite side from his shooting hand?

[image: Modern "reverse" holster]

Comment: 's point is quite salient.  Visual media has a long history of such exotic depictions, which, in some sense can be seen as gimmicks to capture the imagination of viewers.  The dual pistols on the belt often seen in Westerns is considered to be such a gimmick. Holding a gun sideways while shooting is a more recent gimmick.

Comment: @cybermike - or the trademark John Woo hold the gun sideways then shoot (more bullets than the gun carries) while diving through the air, with explosions.

Answer (score 2):

There is only one scene where Kevin Hart wears his police uniform with a gun. He never had his gun backwards.

[image]

You can see his gun in the above picture.

[image]

You can see a taser here.

You could have been confused because he is carrying a lot of things on his belt.

Answer (score 2):

The reason he (or others) might wear their pistol backwards is because it enables a seated person to draw easier than if the gun was in the more "traditional" style. This is called "Cavlary Style" or Cavalry draw as noted here (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cavalry_draw)

ps: I would have felt better leaving this as a comment than a specific answer, but I'm 3 points shy of commenting.